# Java Parser for LHS brackets URL parameters

Tags: java, filter, parameters, qs

Is there an established Java library for parsing URL parameters with nested LHS brackets,like what might be outputted through js qs? Maybe taking all of the params and mapping them to an object? Or do people typically just manually parse those?

ex:`GET /items?filter[price][gte]=10&filter[price][lte]=100&name=apple`

I've found a couple of small personal projects that look promising, but just wondering what other people are using.

Comment: You should ask about the problem that you are trying to resolve rather than asking for recommendations.